# Bluetooth between NXT and android smartphone

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, nxt

I want my android smartphone to receive a message from a Lego Mindstorms NXT-unit. Once the message has been sent, the phone will then dial the first number in a list and if it gets a "busy signal" or no answer for four signals, dial the next number in a list and display a "Alarm failed" if noone answers. So, How do I program the phone to activate the dialer once it's gotten the message? I can do the lists and stuff but I'm mostly having problems with activating dialer once it gets the message via bluetooth.

I'm using Eclipse for the android app and I find it hard to use lejos (I haven't really found any way to learn about it and I just keep running into problems) so I'm programming the NXT-unit in NXT-G.

Comment: The text of your question makes it sound more like the emphasis is on placing a phone call than on the bluetooth messaging.